# Flask: Config.py - how to separate dev from production?

Tags: python, flask

I was reading the documentation about [configuration files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#development-production) in flask:

Following the same idea, I have introduced a `config.py` at my root.
and entered this in there:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://:memory:'


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    use_reloader = False
    port = 6000
```

Within my server.py I have the following:

```
http_root = os.path.abspath( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../www") )
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder=http_root, static_url_path="/app")
app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(            
            port = app.config['port'],
            use_reloader=False,
            debug = app.config['DEBUG']
            )
```

Yet when I run the server, I get `KeyError: 'port'`
What am I missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`config.from_object`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/config.py#L138):

```
def from_object(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        obj = import_string(obj)
    for key in dir(obj):
        if key.isupper():
            self[key] = getattr(obj, key)
```

There are checking for lowcase names (also, `__dict__`, `__repr__` and etc.). So will use UPCASE config variables.